# How do I recreate a merge commit after a rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I just rebased an experiment branch to be up to date with the new mainline.  That branch had a feature branch within it.  I wanted to preserve it, but now it's lost.  I'd like to recreate it without having to do the rebase again (there were several time consuming conflicts).  How can I do this?

I started with this.

```
Z [stable]
|
Y
…
|
| J [experiment]
| |\
| | I
| | |
| | H
| | |
| | G
| |/
| F
| |
| E
|/
D [last-sync-with-stable]
…
```

After `git rebase --ignore-whitespace --onto stable last-sync-with-stable experiment` I wound up with this.

```
I1 [experiment]
|
H1
|
G1
|
F1
|
E1
|
Z [stable]
|
Y
…
```

The merge commit, J, is lost and with it the fact that G, H and I were all done as a unit along with the rationale, caveats and issue number in J's log message. I would like that back. I want this.

```
J1 [experiment]
|\
| I1
| |
| H1
| |
| G1
|/
F1
|
E1
|
Z [stable]
|
Y
…
```

I now know I should have run `rebase` with `--preserve-merges`, but I don't want to have to re-run the rebase and fix all the conflicts again.

How can I preserve the merge commit, its log message, author dates and times and all that without having to fix the conflicts all over again? I realize I could manually perform the merge again, copy the log message, set the author date and all that... I'm looking for a more elegant way for future use. Sort of like a `cherry-pick` for merge commits.

Comment: [rerere](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) would have helped with this but I don't think it can be retroactively turned on.

Comment: @CaptainMurphy Yeah, alas I discovered that too late.

Comment: The answer is always `rerere` and the followup is always "oops, forgot to turn it on".  I believe it should be easy to make a program that you point at a previous merge you did, say "turn on rerere, re-do the merge, use the previous merge result as my resolutions, and record".  I haven't actually tried to code this but it sounds like you have an ideal setup.  The code basically amounts to: turn on rerere, force the merge to happen again (on an anonymous branch), extract the merge resolutions from the previous merge, and use `git add` / `git commit` to record them.